# TextField input validation pattern

Tags: swift, validation, input, textfield

In a ViewController I have three text fields (mail, password, repeat password). Before sending data to the server I do a little validation (check if text exists, if mail is valid, etc.).

I do this way:

```
let email = emailTextfield.text
let password = passwordTextfield.text
let repeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextfield.text

        if let e = email {
            if let p = password {
                if let rp = repeatPassword{

                    if(e.isEmpty || p.isEmpty || rp.isEmpty){//cut mail validation...
```

The question is: is this the best way to do it? Is there any better (maybe more compact) way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Swift 2.0 or so, you no longer need to construct [an optional binding pyramid of doom](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/12/08/swift-optional-pyramids-of-doom.html), but can use several bindings (as well as boolean conditionals) in the same `if` statment. E.g.:

```
if let email = emailTextfield.text, !email.isEmpty,
   let password = passwordTextfield.text, !password.isEmpty,
   let repeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextfield.text, !repeatPassword.isEmpty  {
    // proceed only for all non-nil and non-empty above ...
}
```

These will naturally short-circuit for first failed binding/`false` conditional met.

Comment: But it's just another kind of pyramid!   ;-)

Comment: @IanBell I wouldn't really refer to this as a pyramid in that context: we don't have to enter nested levels of if blocks (as the pre-Swift 2.0 users had to suffer from). Maybe this is more of a slightly wide base platform, instead? :)

Comment: I was joking  :-)

Comment: @IanBell I was trying to joke back, but realize upon reading my answering comment that the comment was a bit too dry for that to be understood!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I can see two solutions:

-The first one is clearer:

```
if let e = email, let p = password, let rp = repeatPassword {
    if e.isEmpty || p.isEmpty || rp.isEmpty {
        // do your things
    }
}
```

-the second one is more compact:

```
if email != nil, password != nil, repeatPassword != nil, (email!.isEmpty || password!.isEmpty || repeatPassword!.isEmpty) {
    // do the things force unwrapping every variable
}
```

the second solution works because if email or password or repeatPassword is nil, the compiler won't continue reading conditions, and consequently won't crash reading for example repeatPassword!.isEmpty as nil.isEmpty

To build on @dfri 's answer, I can think of this solution (non tested) :

```
if let e = email, let p = password, let rp = repeatPassword, (e.isEmpty, p.isEmpty, rp.isEmpty) {
     // cut mail validation
}
```

the last one, if works, is obviously the most elegant solution and I'll delete it as soon as @dfri updates his solution to comply with your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if let email = emailTextfield.text where !email.isEmpty,
    let password = passwordTextfield.text where !password.isEmpty,
    let repeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextfield.text where !repeatPassword.isEmpty  {
    // Go for it.
}
```

Comment: Note that this is [_exactly_ the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40426153/4573247) I've already posted, but using deprecated syntax (`... where`).

Comment: Yes, it is, but since when is `where` deprecated?

Comment: Since Swift 3.0, see evolution proposal [SE-0099: Restructuring Condition Clauses](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md) (note that your code above doesn't compile for Swift >= 3.0).

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do 
`if email?.isEmpty || password?.isEmpty || repeatPassword?.isEmpty { //break }`

Don't worry about nil value, let it as optionnal and everything will be fine.

Comment: But at a certain point I must send that value to the server, shouldn't be unwrapped?

Comment: Ok so, you can do all variables assignation in one if: `if let ..., ..., ...`